# How To : Get latest DocuSign Connect result by API call

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I have configured my DocuSign Connect and retrieves exactly what I need for my application through a webhook listner.

I was wondering if it is possible to get the exact same result as delivered to the webhook listner by a direct API call ?

I am aware of polling restrictions in DocuSign API, but for some application scenarios I need to be able to get the latest DocuSign Connect result by a direct API call.

If this is possible, please provide instruction for how to make such a direct API call through POSTMAN.

NOTE : I am not a developer, so please provide instructions for dummies ;-)

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to search DocuSign documentation for instructions on how to make the API call but can´t find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you open a direct ticket with DocuSign support, since the ideal would be to be able to schedule a call to be able to guide you step by step on the use of the DocuSign and Connect APIs.

https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/How-Do-I-Open-a-Case-in-the-DocuSign-Support-Center?language=en_US

Regards,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

I opened a case with DocuSign Support who replied that Connect internally accesses the DocuSign API to retrieve envelope data.

The schema used by Connect is not perfectly aligned with the response from the API, although there is substantial similarity.

So to solve my problem I did direct get Envelope API calls which actually, for the data that I needed, matched 100% to what i got from Connect.